# Como corretamente validar um código que deve ser inteiro através do $_GET?

Tags: php

Eu quero saber como validar um código que deve ser inteiro através do $_GET?

Por exemplo, tenho um GET chamado id e ele teoricamente sempre deve ser inteiro (1,2,3,4,5...). Da maneira que estou validando é correta?

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
```

Comment: Com o `filter_input` não é necessário validar. Se ele for inteiro e ter a flag para validar inteiros, a variável terá um valor, se não, será nulo.

Comment: A não sabia, então vou tirar a validação